# CSS Pseudo Lag with jQuery slideToggle

Tags: jquery, css, slidetoggle

I am using the CSS pseudo `:before` to create an arrow in a navigation bar I have and am also using jQuery `slideToggle()` to display the `ul` in that way. However, when you hover over it, the transition will still happen but the arrow will have a slight delay and then appear. To see an example which is much easier as you can see it happen, see http://applefanatic.co.uk and hover over "iPad" for example.

I am new to jQuery so I might be missing something. I know the jQuery code works, it's just the delay I am having.

Thanks.

EDIT: Changed the navigation bar and removed the CSS arrow, this is no longer relevant but will leave the question here in case others need the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because jQuery `slideToggle()` will apply `overflow:hidden` to the element that is being animated and removes once the animation is completed.

To fix this just add `overflow:visible !important` to `ul` in your stylesheet.

Comment: That DID work. Sorry, I didn't think I'd need the !important at the end. Thanks every much.

Comment: Also I've just noticed (it's a different issue but perhaps you could help) when you hover over "Articles" the text in the li's appears before the toggle completes and looks really weird. Any ideas there?

Comment: Ah, it is because of what you suggested, if I remove that, the toggle is fine but then the arrow delays. I am back to square one! Any ideas?

Comment: Please check the link http://jsfiddle.net/4fq29m5c/1/ for the fix. But this requires a little change in the markup.  Alternatively you can do a smoother animation without changing markup using CSS animations.